# Как передать TWebBrowser cookie, из TCookieManager

Tags: webbrowser, delphi-xe7, firemonkey

Есть multidevice application (FMX), авторизация на сайте происходит посредством TIdHttp, после чего создаются куки в TCookieManager. Необходимо передать эти куки в TWebBrowser, чтобы отобразить страницу после авторизации. Либо имеется ли возможность с помощью чего, отобразить HTML, полученный от TIdHTTP?

Answer (score 1):

Имеющийся локальный html можно отобразить, используя методы `TWebBrowser.LoadFromStrings` или `TWebBrowser.Navigate`. Во втором случае нужно в качестве URL указать путь к файлу типа `file://`.

В XE7 (при компиляции под iOS) метод `Navigate` для загрузки локального файла я не рекомендую использовать - метод обработки ссылок `file://` написан криво и может свалиться с AV, требуется его правка.

Непосредственно в веббраузер передать куку нельзя, такого кроссплатформенного метода не предусмотрено. Однако, можно посмотреть в сторону `javascript` - если с использованием кода, исполняемого на веб-странице, можно внедрить cookie - то стоит воспользоваться методом `TWebBrowser.EvaluateJavaScript`.

Update: действительно, с использованием Javascript можно внедрить cookie. см. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). Вкратце - кука задается через `document.cookie`.

Т.е. можно сделать (примерно) так:

```
 myWB.EvaluateJavaScript('document.cookie="username=John Doe"');
```